# is there a more efficient way of overloading operators than the way I have in python?

Tags: python, function, class, operator-overloading

I have a Python class which lets you initialize lines, with two x-y coordinate points. I also have a function to add two lines together as follows:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        ...

    def __add__(self, other):
        new_x1 = self.x1 + other.x1
        new_y1 = self.y1 + other.y1
        new_x2 = self.x2 + other.x2
        new_y2 = self.y2 + other.y2
        return Line(new_x1, new_y1, new_x2, new_y2)
```

I have very similar functions for subtraction and multiplication, they're the same as the add function with a different operator symbol inside.

My question is, is there a better or more efficient way to write this?

Comment: Why is the overloaded addition in a `Line` class returning a `Point` object? What is the meaning of the addition of two `Point` items? (To the exception of affine geometry, you don't add points)

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. it's supposed to be Line

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more concise:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
       self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2 = x1, y1, x2, y2

    def operation(self, other, op):
        new_x1 = op(self.x1, other.x1)
        new_y1 = op(self.y1, other.y1)
        new_x2 = op(self.x2, other.x2)
        new_y2 = op(self.y2, other.y2)
        return Point(new_x1, new_y1, new_x2, new_y2)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.operation(other, float.__add__)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.operation(other, float.__sub__)
```

Comment: The `op` parameter is not used in `operation()`.

Comment: @AKX look again please. It is used 4 times.

Comment: No, the `op` name is not used. You probably mean something like `getattr(self.x1, op)` to access an attribute by name.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage similarities. If you also define `__neg__` you get slightly easier add/sub implementations as sub == -add

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2 = x1, y1, x2, y2

    def __add__(self, other):
        new_x1 = self.x1 + other.x1
        new_y1 = self.y1 + other.y1
        new_x2 = self.x2 + other.x2
        new_y2 = self.y2 + other.y2
        return Line(new_x1, new_y1, new_x2, new_y2)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self + (-other)  # leverage __neg__

    def __neg__(self):
        return Line(-self.x1,-self.y1,-self.x2,-self.y2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.x1}/{self.y1})->({self.x2}/{self.y2})"


l = Line(0,0,10,10)
l2 = Line(5,5,.20,20)

print(l) 
print(l2) 
print(l-l2)
```

Output:

```
(0/0)->(10/10)
(5/5)->(0.2/20)
(-5/-5)->(9.8/-10)
```

but most of the time this wont make much sense because operations might vary wildly depending on the domain your class lives in.

Answer (score 0):

The operation thing of @Blotosmeteks answer is great. But to add to that you can also do.

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2 = float(x1), float(y1), float(x2), float(y2)

    def operation(self, other, op):  # Removing the declarations on multiple lines here.
        return Point(op(self.x1, other.x1), op(self.y1, other.y1),
                op(self.x2, other.x2), op(self.y2, other.y2))

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.operation(other, float.__add__)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.operation(other, float.__sub__)
```

Comment: The `op` parameter is not used in `operation()`.